# Access Report Group by True/False Field fails with "No Matching Records"

Tags: ms-access, report, grouping

I have a report I am designing in Access that has True/False fields as the underlying data source with the column named Active?, showing any clients that are currently active.  I am trying to create a group by their status(ie, active or inactive), but I keep getting the message box "No Matching Records Found"  popping up whenever I try and run the report.

I am pretty sure there must be some type of way to accomplish this, but I haven't been able to figure it out or find it online.  Any help would be appreciated with this.

Comment: The question mark in "Active?" is really part of the column name? If yes I suggest you remove it from the name. If that's not possible, you should strictly enclose that name in square brackets wherever you use it.

Comment: @PhilS I can do that, but that doesn't answer the question at all, and has nothing to do with why it isn't working. I had it named "IsActive" prior to that and the same result.

Comment: Post code for analysis. Show the report RecordSource SQL. Show code that opens the report.

Comment: @MattE OK, it was a wild guess. - We need more info here. "No Matching Records Found" is a very unusual error message in Access. I guess there is something special about your scenario you did not mention yet. Usually this should be a trivial operation with little potential for error.

Comment: The error comes from not intrinsically being able to group based on a Boolean value.  I don't see where the need to post all this detailed info comes from.  It's a basic question on how to group based on a Boolean value.  With all the extras and features nobody uses they've designed how can they be missing a feature that automatically will allow you to group by a Boolean value?    It's a pretty simple thing.  If True, it's one group, if False it's another.